# How many elements of order 3 in this set of 2×2 matrices?

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Let $M$ be a group, $M=\bigg  \{ \bigg(
  {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   0 & c \\
  \end{array} } \bigg)\bigg| a,c \in \mathbb{Z}_3\setminus \{0\},
b\in \mathbb{Z}_3
\bigg \}$

The elements of $M$ of order 3 are
${\bigg(\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & b \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}\bigg) }$.

I thought those were ${\bigg(\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}\bigg) }, {\bigg(\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}\bigg) },{\bigg(\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 2 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}\bigg) }$, since $b \in \mathbb{Z}_3$.

But my answer sheet doesn't mention ${\bigg(\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
\end{array}} \bigg )
$, but that's just a mistake in the sheet, right? Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Are you considering *additive* order instead of *multiplicative* order?

Comment: Nope, I was just being dumb. Coulda been that though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order of

$$
I = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\
0& 1
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

is 1 not 3 since $I^1 = e$ where $e$ is your identity element.

Comment: Yes, of course! I do not feel super clever atm, lol =(

Answer (score 7):

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
is the identity, and as such has order one, not 3.